# String.call.call type?

Tags: javascript, function, google-chrome

This is true (run it in the console in Google Chrome):

```
typeof String.call.call === 'function'
```

But calling it as
`String.call.call()` throws an error saying it's not a function:
**Uncaught TypeError: String.call.call is not a function
    at :1:13**

Why trying to call a function (as per its `typeof` definition) throws an error saying it's not a function? Is it actually a function or not?

Note this happens to other classes such as Number, Function or others that inherit the `.call` method.

Comment: `var call = Function.call; call();` fails for the same reason. Before someone answers, can you see why now?

Comment: @PatrickRoberts That is the same issue, but written on two lines, I still fail to see why something whose type is `function` is treated as `not a function` when evaluated.

Comment: Imagine in C you declare a void pointer without initializing it, typecast it to some kind of function and then try to execute it. Same thing, basically. Point is, _what_ are you calling, exactly? Who knows, but likely there's no function there.

Comment: I think I understand, it's just probably Chrome that throws a "bad" error code, I see trying the same thing in IE or FireFox leads to different (more logic) errors.

Answer (score 1):

Let's try to break this down into more manageable pieces.

`String` is a constructor (or a static function / constructor hybrid, whatever you want to call it), and as such, it inherits from `Function.prototype`, because it is a function.

`call` is a function that executes its context (the `this`) with the context given to it in the first parameter:

```js
console.log(String.call(true));
console.log(Array.call(null));
console.log(Function.call('so?'));
console.log(Object.call(/notice me/));
```

Let's look at a more official definition for [`Function.call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call):

> The `call()` method calls a `function` with a given `this` value and `arguments` provided individually.
>
> ```
> function.call(thisArg, arg1, arg2, ...)
> ```

Now, the interesting part here is noting that these three are identical:

```js
'use strict';

var callRef = String.call; // Function.call, Array.call, Boolean.call, all of them are ===

console.log(String(/make me into a string/));
console.log(String.call(undefined, /make me into a string/));
console.log(callRef.call(String, undefined, /make me into a string/));
```

The `callRef.call(String)` means, call `callRef()` with the context of `String`, which is to say, execute `String()` with the context and parameters provided in the following arguments.

As we recall, the context doesn't really matter, but now we know that the first parameter of `callRef.call()` *does* matter, because it determines what function to execute, because it's telling `callRef()` what *its* context is, which gets executed as a function with the context provided in the next parameter.

Now reflecting on the initial question, what happens when we attempt to execute `String.call.call()`? Well, if a parameter is not specified, it is `undefined`, and we know that `typeof undefined !== 'function'`.

So here's my final answer:

`String.call.call()` is indeed a function... but all it's doing is attempting to execute `undefined` as a function, which obviously isn't.

```js
String.call.call();
```

I hope this has been an interesting and informative explanation.